# TVRP API Authorization

Tags: here-api

I have successfully created an Bearer Token and i would like to request data from the Tour Planning/VRP API. However, i always get the following response: { "error": "Forbidden", "error_description": "These credentials do not authorize access" }

If i try to make the request with the APIKey instead of the Bearer Token, I don't get autenthification.

Authorization by token and apikey work fine for me, I have used it at the same time in other methods and it works fine. But none of these two authorization methods works:

POST https://vrp.api.here.com/v1/problems
Authorization: Bearer <My_Token>

or

POST https://vrp.api.here.com/v1/problems?apikey=My_ApiKey

with this Body:

```
{
  "plan": {
    "jobs": [
      {
        "id": "myJob",
        "places": {
          "delivery": {
            "location": {"lat": 52.46642, "lng": 13.28124},
            "times": [["2019-07-04T10:00:00.000Z","2019-07-04T12:00:00.000Z"]],
            "duration": 180
          }
        },
        "demand": [1]
      }
    ]
  },
  "fleet": {
    "types": [
      {
        "id": "myVehicle",
        "profile": "normal_car",
        "costs": {
          "distance": 0.0002,
          "time": 0.004806,
          "fixed": 22
        },
        "shifts": [{
          "start": {
            "time": "2019-07-04T09:00:00Z",
            "location": {"lat": 52.52568, "lng": 13.45345}
          },
          "end": {
            "time": "2019-07-04T18:00:00Z",
            "location": {"lat": 52.52568, "lng": 13.45345}
          }
        }],
        "limits": {
          "maxDistance": 300000,
          "shiftTime": 28800
        },
        "capacity": [10],
        "amount": 1
      }
    ],
    "profiles": [{
      "name": "normal_car",
      "type": "car",
      "departureTime": "2019-07-04T09:15:00Z"
     }]
  }
}
```

Thanks Jose

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using your Freemium account, which does not include access to the Tour Planning API at this point. We are working on an update for the developer portal that will make it more clear which APIs are included. If you need access please use the contact us form on the developer portal to reach out to a HERE representative.